# Array.Find gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page is crashing due to a null element in Array.Find command:

```
     if (m_dynamicCheckBoxLists != null)
            {
                CheckBoxList myCbl1 = Array.Find(m_dynamicCheckBoxLists, element => element.ID == strFieldId);
```

using breakpoints, I can see element is null.

How do I get round this without crashing?

Comment: `Array.Find(m_dynamicCheckBoxLists, element => element != null && element.ID == strFieldId);`?

Comment: Is it expected that `m_dynamicCheckBoxLists` will have null elements?

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing:

```
element => element.ID == strFieldId
```

with:

```
element => element != null && element.ID == strFieldId
```

Because `&&` short-circuits, it won't evaluate `element.ID == strFieldId` in the case where `element == null`.